# Return all the distinct values of Product Column using T-SQL all values should be Distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Take the following table:

| ID | Products |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | xx,yy,xx |
| 13 | yy,xx,yy |
| 14 | tt,xx,tt |
| 15 | yy,yy,yy |

I need a T-SQL to give me   distinct Values  in the Products Column

Required Result as below:

| ID | Products |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | xx,yy |
| 13 | yy,xx |
| 14 | tt,xx |
| 15 | yy |

Comment: While technically you can use functions like STRING_SPLIT and STRING_AGG to manipulate the values, ultimately you could make things a lot easier on yourself by not storing values as comma separated strings ....

Comment: Fixing your design is what you should be doing here, then you could ensure that you can't have duplicates in the first place with a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`/`UNIQUE INDEX`.

Comment: Is the last `ID` really supposed to be 14? Not much of an `ID` if so.

Comment: Sorry i have fixed the ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `STRING_SPLIT`,`distinct` and  `string_agg` as follows

```
SELECT ID,
       String_agg(value, ',') AS Products
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT ID,
                        value
        FROM   (SELECT ID,
                       a.value
                FROM   table
                       CROSS apply String_split(products, ',') a) b) c
GROUP  BY ID
```

Comment: Thanks @ RF1991 has worked

Comment: If it works, accept the answer as the solution, @BashiWaneMwale , but again, take note of the comments; fix your design, that is the *real* solution.